# single dependency in ruby job order list is duplicating on its result

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a jobs list and have written a spec to the following question where one item in the list depends on another. The result i have is returning the list item c twice. The question is as follows:

```
Given the following job structure:

a =>
b => c
c =>
The result should be a sequence that positions c before b, containing all three jobs abc.
```

I am confused because my test is failing as follows

```
  1) JobsList should return ordered multiple jobs with the dependency if multiple jobs with single dependency were supplied
     Failure/Error: expect(JobsList.sequence({'a' => nil, 'b' => 'c', 'c' => nil})).to eq ['a', 'c', 'b']

       expected: ["a", "c", "b"]
            got: ["a", "c", "c", "b"]

       (compared using ==)
```

I am at a loss here as to what i am doing wrong could anyone offer any suggestions?

**jobs_list_spec**

```
require 'jobs_list'

describe JobsList do

    it "should return an empty sequence of jobs if a blank hash was supplied" do 
        expect(JobsList.sequence({})).to eq []      
    end


    it "should return an single job character if a single jobs was supplied" do 
        expect(JobsList.sequence({'a' => nil})).to eq ['a']     
    end

    it "should return multiple jobs characters if a multiple jobs were supplied" do 
        expect(JobsList.sequence({'a' => nil, 'b' => nil, 'c' => nil})).to eq ['a', 'b', 'c']       
    end

    it "should return ordered multiple jobs with the dependency if multiple jobs with single dependency were supplied" do 
        expect(JobsList.sequence({'a' => nil, 'b' => 'c', 'c' => nil})).to eq ['a', 'c', 'b']       
    end
```

**jobs_list.rb**

```
class JobsList
    def self.sequence(jobs={})
        grouped_jobs = jobs.group_by{|k, v| v}
        grouped_jobs.map do |k,v|
            array = []
            if k 
                array = array + [k]
            end
            array = array + v.map{|a| a[0]}
        end.flatten
    end
end
```

Comment: Why do you think your algorithm should work? If you can explain your reasoning someone might spot a flaw (or a difference between your inplementation and what you think you have implemented)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I got your problem, but you can try this piece of code.

```
class JobsList
  def self.sequence(jobs={})
    jobs.to_a.flatten.uniq.compact
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Although it did not work on its own when i added uniq.compact to the end of the code it did. Could you possible explain your logic behind this?

Comment: So the code remained the same as above but where i had end.flatten i instead had end.flatten.uniq.compact

Comment: Well, if you just want to leave your code, then you can add only uniq. It'll delete duplicate elements from an array. Compact method deletes nil elements from an array, so you can avoid using conditional statement in your code this way.
I'd suggest you to rework this method a bit, and maybe the class itself. For now it's purpose isn't clear, at least for me. And thats bad, especially if someone besides you is going to maintain that code.

Answer (score 1):

Some pointers that may help:

1. Try to modify the interface of the class or move the logic to the instance of the class rather than in the class method as it will make it difficult to work with state.
2. Secondly try to split functionality into tiny classes with expressive names, it will help you think through the logic more easily.

If you want to keep the current class based interface, think about the following to structure your class method:

```
def self.sequence(jobs)
  JobList.new(jobs).sequence
end
```

Now, you can move your logic into instance methods; not saying instances cannot be shared between class methods. But this approach may be easier to reason out.

If you are totally stuck, have a look how the logic could be split up in the [Ordered Job Kata](https://github.com/JikkuJose/katas/tree/master/ordered_jobs/02) I solved.

Answer (score -1):

```
    def self.sequence(jobs={})
    puts 'hi'
    grouped_jobs = jobs.group_by{|k, v| v}
    grouped_jobs.map do |k,v|
        array = []
        if k 
            array = array + [k]
        end
        array = array + v.map{|a| a[0]}
    end.flatten.uniq.compact
end
```

Comment: It is a good idea to *explain* your code, in addition to posting it.